# How to identify the subspecies/breed of a bee

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing, bees

I have been a beekeeper for a number of years and originally obtained my first colonies from a guy in my neighbourhood. However, when I sell bees to someone else, they typically ask what *species* of the [European/Western honeybee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_honey_bee) (Apis mellifera) I have/they're buying. Technically, they're after the [*subspecies* or *breed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apis_mellifera_subspecies) (like Italian, Carniolan, Buckfast, ...), but I don't know what to tell them. I just call them local (or locally-adapted) bees.

Is there a way that one can find out the subspecies/breed I currently have? Perhaps through DNA analysis/sequencing or some other kind of scientific analysis? Regardless, is such subspecies identification available/accessible to the hobby beekeeper (should read as being relatively inexpensive)?

Images like the following are circulated to estimate one's breed:

[image]

However, traits are hardly a definitive assessment of a breed, especially if you consider how close some of the breeds are listed above. For example, what's the difference in a trait ranked 5 and 6, say.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about apiculture, but in academic research it is typical that people use [microsatellite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsatellite) markers for identifying subspecies of bees. Microsatellite are repetitive regions of the genome that are useful in at identifying different species/subspecies, as well as for generating pedigrees and paternity analysis. Different species/subspecies have different numbers of repeats in a particular microsatellites, and these differing number of repeats are heritable. People use microsatellites because they are cheap, easy to run and reliable for identifying species/subspecies. Because there can be many different alleles (or different numbers of repeats) at a given microsatellite locus, so you only need relatively few microsatellites in total to identify individuals.

An example can be found in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1206644/). They used 7 microsatellite loci and could reliably identify between different African and European sub-species. It is worth a read of the intro:

> Recent population genetic surveys in human (Bow- COCK et al.
> 1994;DIRIENZO et al. 1994) and other mammals (GOTTELLE et al. 1994;
> TAEOR et al. 1994) and in bumble bees (A. ESTOUP,M. SOLIGNAJC. ,M.
> CORNUET and A. SCHOLL unpublished results) have shown that
> microsatellites are highly efficient at differentiating
> populations or groups of populations. In this paper, we investigate their
> usefulness for honey bee population studies by adressing the
> following specific questions: Are the three evolutionary branches
> inferred from morphometry and mtDNA confirmed by microsatellite
> data? Are microsatellites useful for differentiating sub-species and
> populations within subspecies? How does the pattern of variability of
> these markers vary between branches/subspecies/populations and which
> factors may be invoked to explain it? Is it possible to assign a given
> colony to its population of origin from microsatellite data and how do
> the individuals from this colony cluster within the population?

**References:**

Estoup A, Garnery L, Solignac M, Cornuet JM. Microsatellite variation in honey bee (Apis mellifera L.) populations: hierarchical genetic structure and test of the infinite allele and stepwise mutation models. Genetics. 1995 Jun;140(2):679-95. PMID: 7498746; PMCID: PMC1206644.

Comment: Are you using the first word in your post, "typically", in an indirect generalized way or from a perspective of insider knowledge/awareness of apiculture? I ask because the paper you quote only cites a *single* additional study of *unpublished* results, which doesn't support the interpretation of "typically" to mean *widespread* as I think is implied from your post's wording. I don't know one way or the other, but I think it'd be good to clarify your wording and possibly explicitly indicate your knowledge of the subject so that future readers know how to frame your response. thanks.

Comment: I slightly misunderstood the post and didn't notice it was talking about bee keepers in particular - I said 'typically' since microsats are (most likely - I don't have direct evidence) used in research to identify different Hymenoptera species/subspecies. I've got a reasonable amount of experience in population genetics of Hymenoptera, so that's what I'm going off. That paper is old, so the citations are out of data, but having a look [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Hymenoptera+microsatellite&btnG=) shows it is still common. Will amend the post to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks! I had a hunch that was the case. Again, I personally don't know one way or the other, and I just wanted to make sure your post was clear to others. Thanks for the update!

Comment: @user438383: You mention "cheap [and] easy to run." Can you elaborate? I'm a beekeeper without any lab access, but I'm interested in this as a side-project. Are there tools available to the laymen to perform identify these *microsatellite markers*?

Comment: @Werner - good question - ill edit in the answer to my post soon.

Comment: @user438383: Any update you can provide?